# Ошибка при компиляции CS1061

Tags: c#

Компилятор пишет сообщение:

> СS1061 "Form1" не содержит определения "eldataTableAdapter", и не
>   удалось найти доступный метод решения. "eldataTableAdapter",
>   принимающий тип "Form1" Convrtation1  в качестве первого аргумента
>   (возможно, пропущена директива using или ссылка на сборку).

ошибку указывает здесь:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: данная строка кода позволяет загрузить данные в таблицу "mydatabase1DataSet.Eldata". При необходимости она может быть перемещена или удалена.
            ***this.eldataTableAdapter***.Fill(this.mydatabase1DataSet.Eldata);
    }
```

Эти строки Visual Studio пишет сам автоматически, эта ошибка подчёркивающая - `this.eldataTableAdapter` ранее не появлялась, стала появляться гораздо позднее. Видимо где то сбились настройки. В чём причина подскажите.

Comment: Покажите где объявлен `eldataTableAdapter`. Возможно, Вы просто случайно его с формы удалили.

Comment: @defaultlocale он не объявлен, и видимо не был объявлен ранее, так как я ранее не удалял eldataTableAdapter, но я переименовывал "Eldata" в "Table" через Источник данных->Изменить набор данных в конструкторе, переименовал в Table, но потом вернул имя Eldata. Это могло повлиять и как исправить в таком случае?

Comment: Если он не объявлен - объявите его. Компилятор не сможет собрать то, что он не знает.

Comment: @Forward поищите поля с названием `adapter` в классе, либо в дизайнере форм. Скорее всего что-то сломалось.